# using scala jar from java project in NetBeans

Tags: java, scala

I'm developing a scala library, which I would like to be used by java applications.

If I set up a java project in netbeans, with a reference to the scala library (jar), I can compile the java project without errors.

However I get problems when running the java project directly from netbeans (code from scala library is not executed e.g. for scala object methods), while when running it without ant (directly with java -jar .... on the command line in the /dist folder) everything works.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Boris

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the NetBeans/Ant logs?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it's impossible to say for sure. However, one possibility leaps immediately to mind: Your Scala library is using Scala types. If you don't have `scala-library.jar` in your Java programs' classpaths, they won't be able to use the Scala classes in your library.

Comment: I already added the scala-library.jar to both, the scala and the java project ... I moved now to netbeans 6.9 but the same problem occurs.